# How to access rules condition values in the rule event?

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I have created a rule (using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)) in which I added 3 conditons. Now I want to access the conditions values in the action that on which condition the action is performed.

I am attaching the screenshot :

[image]

As shown in the screenshot, I want to access

```
[commerce-license:type], Data value: Diamond Subscription
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Could it be that "event" should be "action" in your title? If so please edit your title. If not: why doesn't it show up anywhere in your actual question?

Comment: If you code conditions on a rule, they all have to be true before the rule is executed. So the value will always be "Diamond Subscription". If you access the value within the rule you'll always get the same result. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it'll be the only thing you need to do to get this to work, but I think you may get closer (= simplify your challenge) by ALSO using the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> ... provides [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) plugins for conditionally altering execution flow directly inside a group of **actions**.

Here is a screenprint of a rule with an action that uses Conditional Rules (though only with an "if"-part here, no "else"):

[image]